# Как мне запустить 2 процесса одновременно?

Tags: python, процесс, multiprocessing

Я делаю будильник на питоне и мне нужно запустить 2 процесса. Первый должен выводить окно, а второй запускать звук. `process1` и `process2`, несмотря на multiprocessing запускаются поочередно, а не одновременно. Вот код:

```
#import for time
from datetime import datetime
#import for interface
from tkinter import *
#import for parallel use
from multiprocessing import *
#import functions
from alarm_interface import window
from alarm_sound import alarm_sound


#Function that checks valid time
def valid_alarm(val_al):
    if int(str(val_al[0:2]))>23 or int(str(val_al[3:5]))>59:
        return "Invalid time"
    else:
        return "Pass"

#Main programm that asks user for title and time for alarm

while True:
    print('Title of the alarm clock:',end=' ')
    name_of_alarm=input('')

    print('Select the desired time. Enter the hour and minute')

    print('Hour:',end='')
    user_time_hour=int(input()[0:2])

    print('Minute:',end='')
    user_time_min=int(input()[0:2])

    user_time="{:02d}:{:02d}".format(user_time_hour,user_time_min)

    #Checking valid time
    if valid_alarm(user_time)=="Invalid time":
        print(valid_alarm(user_time))
    else:
        print(("The alarm clock is set to {:02d}:{:02d}").format(user_time_hour,user_time_min))
        break

#Main programm that compares current time and user time
while True:

    current_time=str(datetime.now().time())[:5]

    if current_time==user_time:
        print(name_of_alarm)
        #multiprocessing
        process1=Process(target=alarm_sound())
        process2=Process(target=window())

        process2.start()
        process1.start()
        process2.join()
        process1.join()
```

Comment: Используй модуль concurrent.futures

Comment: @Printon зачем они тут?

Comment: Что-бы разбить на процессы как он хочет

Comment: они уже разбиты - смотрите код то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А можно делать не *процессы*, а *потоки*, то есть использовать `threading.Thread`:

```py
from threading import Thread

...

process1 = Thread(target=alarm_sound)
process2 = Thread(target=window)

process1.start()
process2.start()

...
```

Также обратите внимание на то что в `target` передаётся функция **без** скобок.

Comment: Если потоки, то лучше возможно будет asyncio использовать, все равно питон работает в одном потоке

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что ты вызываешь функцию до запуска процесса, нужно в Process() передавать ссылку на функцию (без ())

Решение с помощью concurrent.futures

Установка - `pip install futures`
Код:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime


def main():
    while True:
        current_time = str(datetime.now().time())[:5]
        if current_time == user_time:
            with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                executor.submit(alarm_sound)
                executor.submit(window)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Более подробно про concurrent.futures - [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPeo_CQJ7j8&t=683s)

Comment: Модуль `concurrent.futures` - встроенный, `pip install ...` не нужен.

Comment: Я подставил ProcessPoolExecutor в свой код,как у вас.Но все равно не выводится ни звук,ни окно.

Comment: Тогда создай процессы как раньше через multiprocessing, только в `Process()` передавай ссылку на функцию. Пример: `process = Process(target=alarm_sound)`

Comment: А вообще должно работать